# How to have the sum of a column (with computed data) in the first row?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In org-mode is it possible to generate a table, where there is a column which contains a value computed from values in the other columns and which contains the sum of these values?

More specifically, at the moment I have a table with seven columns, where the last two columns contain values computed from values in the other columns using the following formula:

```
#+TBLFM: $6=$4-$3;t::$7=$4-$3-$2;t
```

I would like to include the sum of the last column.  Is this possible? If yes, how can this be achieved? When I tried to do this I always got zero. Ideally I would like to have the sum somewhere outside of the table or in the last row (even if I add new rows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use cell formulas (prefixed by `:=` instead of `=`) for your results.

The example below gives the sum of the last column both at the first and the last rows.

```
|      |      | 8   |
| Col1 | Col2 | Sum |
|------+------+-----|
| 1    | 3    | 4   |
| 2    | 8    | 10  |
| 3    | -9   | -6  |
|------+------+-----|
|      |      | 8   |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2::@1$3=vsum(@I..@II)::@6$3=vsum(@I..@II)
```

`vsum` sums a vector of numbers; `@I` and `@II` refer to the first and second hlines.

Comment: I still get zero as a result. Is it possible that the reason is the `;t` part which I need since I am dealing with times. Adding this also "breaks" your example.

Comment: Tested my example with `;T` mode on all formulas and times for all cells, and it works OK. Note the uppercase `T` (lowercase `t` gives results in decimal hours instead of H:M:S).

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem: I started the table with `|-----....` and then it does not work but without this line it does. (By the way, I really want `;t` instead of `;T` since I want to the total time in decimal hours).

Comment: For general number (no times), it should be vsum(@I..II). See [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Field-and-range-formulas.html#Field-and-range-formulas).

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `orgtbl-aggregate` package available on http://melpa.org

The sum of `Col1` and `Col2` is given in the aggregated table below.

```
#+name: cc
| Col1 | Col2 | Sum8 |
|------+------+------|
|    1 |    3 |    4 |
|    2 |    8 |   10 |
|    3 |   -9 |   -6 |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "cc" :cols "vsum(Col1+Col2)"
| vsum(Col1+Col2) |
|-----------------|
|               8 |
#+END:
```

Documentation here: https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate